# Definição das regras do RealTimeDatabase

Tags: json, firebase, ionic3

Como deve ser minhas regras, para que um usuário logado no app tenha acesso, possa ler e escrever apenas nos seus pedidos ???

```
{
```

"pedidos" : {
    "-LMqiTIhAr-VUMKpq8FD" : {
      "name" : "asdasdsa",
      "tel" : "213"
    },
    "-LMr1wgwinGyew0rVpWs" : {
      "name" : "sadasd",
      "tel" : "123"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "-LMrEQ9Jb7KbkaqhHyMQ" : {
      "cnpj" : "123456",
      "email" : "teste@teste.com"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Para aplicar a regra de acesso dos pedidos (e do próprio usuário), será necessário adicionar o UID (ID de usuário do Firebase Authentication) no caminho que será controlado.

UID do usuário exemplo: "rvCXWGhMkbYul6wS9gfxQSAXbmq1"

```
{  
   "pedidos":{  
      "rvCXWGhMkbYul6wS9gfxQSAXbmq1":{  
         "-LMqiTIhAr-VUMKpq8FD":{  
            "name":"asdasdsa",
            "tel":"213"
         },
         "-LMr1wgwinGyew0rVpWs":{  
            "name":"sadasd",
            "tel":"123"
         }
      }
   },
   "users":{  
      "rvCXWGhMkbYul6wS9gfxQSAXbmq1":{  
         "cnpj":"123456",
         "email":"teste@teste.com"
      }
   }
}
```

Regra para gravação e leitura:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "pedidos": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fonte: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/?hl=pt-br